# uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails (NameError)

Tags: sass, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Getting below error when running rails s.

```
/home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb:11:in `block in <class:Engine>': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Rails (NameError)

from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/dev/Desktop/todo/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dev/Desktop/todo/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /home/dev/Desktop/todo/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/dev/Desktop/todo/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help

Comment: Where is the code that causes this error?

Comment: Thanks Blip for you concern. Please ignore it's fixed now. it was bootstrap-sass version issue.

Comment: If it is solved now, please post the answer to the question or remove the question

Comment: 15 people voting up the answer to this question. How is this not useful? Oh, and I've just reproduced it. That's why I'm here.

Also, no idea how to "improve" this question. It's spot on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

bootstrap-sass is no longer compatible with Rails 3. The latest version of bootstrap-sass compatible with Rails 3.2 is v3.1.1.0.

Comment: This isn't true. The gemspec specifies no rails version requirements, and the changelog does not mention dropping support. That would require a major version bump. Anecdotally, we've been using 3.3.5.1 with Rails 3.2.x in production for quite some time.

Comment: It worked for me as charm.

Comment: @naiyyar is right, 3.1.1.0 is the latest compatible version with 3.2, see here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#rails-32x